# Mod Rewrite MS Hosting Hide Long Annoying URL By displaying the short URL?

Tags: asp.net, mod-rewrite, short-url

Scenario : I have a PHP Forum and a Asp.Net site hosted on Linux and MS Hosting respectively (obvious right?!).

My domain ABC.com is currently configured with PHP host whereas my ASP.Net site is using the default 1and1 generated URL (s0987465.onlinehome.us).

So my question is, how to display ABC.com for any URL that includes s0987465.onlinehome.us?

**Example : s0987465.onlinehome.us/test.aspx?id=100 should display ABC.com or ABC.com/test.aspx?id=100 in the address bar by displaying content generated by s0987465.onlinehome.us?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you thought about simply using a subdomain of *abc.com* on your ASP.Net site?  Eg.  *www2.abc.com*.
2. On top of that, or otherwise, you can display your pages from your ASP.Net site in an IFrame on your PHP site.  That would mask the original domain from your ASP.Net.
3. Further.  Some ASP.Net hosting firms support PHP.  So you can run both the PHP and ASP.Net sites on a single domain.

But I don't think you can rewrite the domain part of a URL.  That would be a *huge* security hole if you could.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kervin.  The webhost is 1and1 (shared hosting - both Linux and MS) and they are a pin to deal with. 

The PHP site is a VBulletin forum which makes it a lot more difficult to tweak (atleast for someone new to VB).

1) I love your www2.abc.com idea. I didn't know we can even do that. Any pointers? 

2) IFrame may be difficult to implement with VBulletin, will explore.

3) Totally ruled out cos' of shared hosting limitations..

Thank you thank you thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, not prob.  Here is the 1and1 doc for subdomains http://faq.1and1.com/domains/subdomains_/2.html .  Not everyone likes them, but I use Godaddy for shared hosting accounts ( when I'm not using amazon web services ) and they've worked very well for me.  For example Godaddy DNS manager allows me to put any IP Address in a subdomain, so I can point that subdomain to any server on the internet.

Comment: The only option I had with 1and1 is a frame redirect/ http redirect to the ASP.Net site from the sub domain (xyz.abc.com) hosted on Linux host and the client is pissed about SEO taking a hit. I don't know what to do :( Is there a 301, 4** redirects or something that can help with SEO in this case?

Comment: I was assuming that you also had your domain name registered with 1and1.  This subdomain has to be registered with company that registered your domain.  In other words you need to be in your DNS admin tool.